# Can't login Ubuntu after plugging out and back Ethernet interface card

Tags: login, ethernet

Please help check the following issue, thank you.

[Issue]
There is not any login issue before plugging out Ethernet interface card.

Then, I plugged out Ethernet interface card and boot up the computer.

In Ubuntu login screen, I input the "correct" password to login.

However, it will returns back to Ubuntu login screen in few seconds.

It was the same situation after plugging back Ethernet interface card.

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks.

[Environment]
(1) Dell Precision Workstation 7920
(2) Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Thanks

Comment: If you're using 16.04.3 (and you weren't listing the installed version) you're out of date as you should be on 16.04.6.  If you're talking about GUI login, it could be you're just out of space in your $HOME or user directory; and thus can still login via text terminal to check, and remove files if necessary (GUI logins require creation of work files which are created in your user directory). Can you login via text terminal (assuming you're not talking about a server).  I'd also suggest `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` asap.

Comment: Hi guiverc,

Thanks for your reply first.

(1) There is enough space in my $HOME or user directory.

(2) After doing "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade", the issue still happened.

Comment: The `dist-upgrade` was mentioned because you mentioned 16.04.3 (16.04.4 was released 1-Mar-2018 so 16.04.3 means you may not have had upgrades since before then unless 16.04.3 was an error). I also can't see the detail from the `sudo apt-get update` so won't know if you had problems anyway.  Outside of space issues you say doesn't apply, I'd next look in BIOS/UEFI config for changes but I don't know your hardware thus no idea how to look for changes because of hardware removal. Video change is next most likely cause so I'd explore & contrast logs/sysd journal before change to that after.